# Define XSL variable without type changing

Tags: java, xslt

I have a variable in my XSL file. Java returned java.util.List into this variable

```
<xsl:variable name="testVariable" select="java:getJavaList()"/>
```

After that this vairable is used in Java by method that takes java.util.List as parameter

```
<xsl:variable name="anotherVariable">
    <xsl:value-of select="java:useTestVariable($testVariable)"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Now requirements were changed to set testVariable value depending on particular condition. I tried this approach

```
    <xsl:variable name="testVariable">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($oneMoreVariable, '%')">
                <xsl:value-of select="java:getValue('%')" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="java:getDefaulValue()" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
```

The problem is that if I define variable in this way, it contains not List, but tree fragment. And I get an exception

> For extension function, could not find method
>   MyClassName.useTestVariable([ExpressionContext,] #RTREEFRAG)

Can somebody please advice what is the correct way to define variable value basing on some condition so, that variable's type would not be changed with tree fragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to do this in XSLT 1.0 as *by definition* any `xsl:variable` with content rather than a `select` must be a result tree fragment. But since you're able to make calls into Java you can put the conditional logic into a Java function, then call that from the variable's `select`.

Comment: Thank you!
I put condition login into java:getJavaList() method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified the  resuts of `java:getValue('%')` and `java:getDefaulValue()` , if these results are coming out be what you expect and still it is a fragement refer this link https://blogs.oracle.com/rammenon/entry/result_tree_fragments_and_node